# Angular 2 Separator missing in URL

Tags: angular, angular-ui

I have a reusable component in dependent package. I have added a image in the reusable component. When I try to use it,  the image added in the reusable component is not displaying.

Conisder **UI-Common** is the dependent project.

**image-use.component.ts**

```
<img class='test'/>
```

**image-use.component.scss**

```
.test {
    background-image: url(..\assets\images\sampleImage.png);
}
```

Consider **base-common** package as a main Package.

**main-base-component.ts**

```
<image-use></image-use>
```

When I try to run the application, I am not getting the image.

When I inspect the element, I have seen the `/` is missing in between the url and filename.

**Expected**: `localhost:8080/base-package/sampleImage.png`

**Result**: `localhost:8080/basepackagesamepleImage.png.`

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue. How can I get he `/` in between url and file name?

Comment: try `.test {
 background-image(/assets/images/sampleImage.png);
 }`

Comment: @PardeepJain Try to add some information along with answer.

Comment: @Carsten Because I am not sure about the solution so posting as a comment, and FYI as per my comment no need to add any explanation. Comment is already self-explanatory

Comment: @Carsten that's a comment, not an answer...

Comment: @PardeepJain Not working.

Answer (score 0):

you have missing `url()`

do it like this

```
.test {
  background-image: url(..\assets\images\sampleImage.png);
 }
```

Comment: added url. Still the same issue.